# How is it possible that the wavelength of a wave can change but the frequency remains the same?

Tags: waves, visible-light, frequency, wavelength

When let's say a beam of light passes through a transparent glass surface, how is the wave able to maintain the same frequency but the wavelength changes ?

Comment: $c=f*\lambda$, if c changes lambda changes, but f can not change.

Comment: The dispersion relation (relation between frequency and wavelength) typically changes with the medium. In the case of glass and air, you can model them as non-dispersive media with different indices if refraction.